# How to initialize a member const vector of a class C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a const vector as member in a class. How can I initialize it?

I know that for constant members the only way we can initialize them is via list initialization at class's constructor function. But exactly how to do it with a vector, I do not know.

For example,

```
class ClassA
{

const std::vector<int> m_Vec;


};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

You can initialize the vector in the class declaration

```
class ClassA
{
    const std::vector<int> m_Vec = {1,2,3};
};
```

Or in the constructor using member initialization

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA(std::vector<int> const& vec) : m_Vec(vec) {}
private:
    const std::vector<int> m_Vec;
};
```

Comment: worth mentioning C++11. Even in 2016, I know.

Answer (score 9):

> I have a const vector as member in a class.

First, I would generally say that you want to avoid it prevents using the class in expected ways (see example below). Also, if the data member is completely encapsulated in the class there is no reason it cannot be a non-const data member while using the classes interface to guarantee it's treated in a *const way* (i.e., instantiations of the class have no way to modify the data member).

#### Bad Example

```
class ClassA
{
    const std::vector<int> m_Vec;
};

int main()
{
    ClassA c1;
    ClassA c2;
    // ...
    c1 = c2; // This doesn't compile!

    return 0;
}
```

> How can I initialize it?

The other answers provide a few different ways to initialize the const data member but **here is one that I didn't see in the other answers**: ***use a function***. I think an advantage to using a function could be if the initialization is complex and possibly dependent on runtime input (e.g., you could update the `init` function to take external state to modify how the `std::vector` is initialized).

#### Free Function Example

```
#include <vector>

namespace
{
    std::vector<int> init()
    {
        std::vector<int> result;
        
        // ... do initialization stuff ...
        
        return result;
    }
}

class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA() : m_Vec(init()) {}

private:    
    const std::vector<int> m_Vec;
};

int main()
{
    ClassA c1;

    return 0;
}
```

#### Member function example

```
#include <vector>

class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA() : m_Vec(init()) {}

private:
    static std::vector<int> init()
    {
        std::vector<int> result;
        
        // ... do initialization stuff ...
        
        return result;
    }

    const std::vector<int> m_Vec;
};

int main()
{
    ClassA c1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: raises the interesting question of how useful is a `const std::vector` with respect to a `const std::array`.

Comment: @user4581301, or even a fixed-size array. But OP wanted a vector :)

Comment: It would be useful to match an existing interface that takes a vector, obviously. I find this to be a bit of an annoyance: there is no clear way in C++ to write a function that can take either a vector, an (std::)array, or an initializer-list, even though this is actually a fairly common problem in my experience, and should be technically feasible.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the anonymous namespace approach.

Comment: i would make the member `init` static to avoid the mistake of accessing other members before they are actually initialized

Answer (score 8):

In c++03 you initialize vector through it's constructor, which is pretty awkward, since you will have to copy it frome some place else. For example:

```
static int initializer[] = {1, 2, 3};

ClassA::ClassA() : m_Vec(initializer, initializer + sizeof(initialize) / sizeof(int)) {}
```

In C++11, this all goes away. In constructor:

```
ClassA::ClassA() : m_Vec{1, 2, 3, 4} {}
```

In-place:

```
std::vector<int> m_Vec{1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Comment: _"In C++2003"_ What's that actually? Did you rather mean _c++03_ standard?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, yes, is it very obscure?

Comment: Sounds as something like _Visual Studio 2003_, that's obscure yes.

Comment: c++2003 is not Y10K compliant.

Comment: @user4581301 _"c++2003 is not Y10K compliant."_ What's _c++2003_ at all?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I've removed offending 20. :)

Comment: @SergeyA Yeah, yeah, I've noticed and immediately upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
class ClassA {
    const std::vector<int> m_Vec {1,2,3};
};
```

Or this:

```
class ClassA {
    ClassA () : m_Vec {1,2,3} {}
    const std::vector<int> m_Vec;
};
```