# Init base class with array of const values

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

My question:

If I propose an array to const elements in a base class, and the array values shall be different in some derived classes, what's the best way to do it?

With a single value it's easy.
With an array I don't know a nice solution.

Of course this code isn't working, it just shall demonstrate the problem and desired behaviour:

```
class Base1 {
public:
  Base1( uint32_t const arr[] ) : m_arr( arr[] ) {}
  // Base1( uint32_t const val ) : m_val( val ) {}
  void f1() {
    int const size = sizeof( m_arr ) / sizeof( uint32_t );
    for( int idx = 0; idx < size; ++idx ) {
      std::cout << "val: " << m_arr[idx] << std::endl;
    }
  }
private:
  uint32_t const m_arr[];
  // uint32_t const m_val;
};

uint32_t const c_arr_derived1[] = { 1, 2, 3 };

// uint32_t const c_val = 3;
class Derived1 : public Base1 {
public:
  Derived1() : Base1 ( c_arr_derived1 ) {}
  //Derived1() : Base1 ( c_val ) {}
};
```

- I probably could define different const arrays in the base header file, 
  use   a define in the derived class and select one of two arrays with 
  that...but that seems awkward.
- I could setup different static const arrays in the base class (so all arrays would always be available in the base class), have an array of them, and use an enum in the derived classes to select one of the arrays in the base class.

Are there any nice solutions?

*Note: the derived classes will finally have pure virtual functions with different implementations, so I want an abstract base class*

*Update, regarding the comments*

- as written above, it's not necessarily valid c++ (g++ compiles  if declared `static uint32_t m_arr[]`, and appropriately defined). The example shall only show what I'm trying to achieve
- I think if not using c++11, I can't use the constructors to initialize arrays; also the arrays are big,  in the ctors I rather want to refer to const arrays defined somewhere else to have a clean look
- I want the data `const` and in ROM, and ideally not copy at construction. If that's possible with `std::vector`, could someone shortly elaborate on an example? Seems to be sth. like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35635430/how-to-initialize-a-member-const-vector-of-a-class-c), I guess. For big arrays with const  data (structs), I'd prefer to have the values somewhere else than in the ctor, though.

Comment: `uint32_t const m_arr[];` is not valid C++ code. And even if it was, using `std::array` or `std::vector` should be preferred

Comment: Also you need to explain what the problem is with initializing the array via the constructors?

Comment: Arrays in c and c++ don't have value semantics. You can't use assignment to copy them around. They also don't have dynamic size. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: I don't see what you are trying to achieve, though, using `std::array` or `std::vector` looks like a good idea.

Comment: Did you consider providing this data via another virtual function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a while ago, anyway the following is what I finally used.

- it does what I want - avoiding heap and runtime initialisation. everything is `const`
- I use an additional member - the const-value containing the `sizeof`

Code:

```
class Base {
public:
  Base( uint32_t const * arr, uint32_t const sz ) : 
      m_arr( arr ), 
      m_sizeof_arr( sz ) {}

  void work() {
    for( int idx = 0; idx < m_sizeof_arr; ++idx ) {
      std::cout << "val: " << m_arr[idx] << std::endl;
    }
  }
private:
  uint32_t const * m_arr;
  uint32_t const m_sizeof_arr;
};

uint32_t const c_arr_derived1[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
  Derived1() : Base ( 
      c_arr_derived1, 
      sizeof( c_arr_derived1 ) / sizeof( uint32_t )  ) {}
};

uint32_t const c_arr_derived2[] = { 4, 5, 6, 7 };
class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
  Derived2() : Base ( 
      c_arr_derived2, 
      sizeof( c_arr_derived2 ) / sizeof( uint32_t ) ) {}
};

int main() {
  Derived1 d1;
  d1.work();
  Derived2 d2;
  d2.work();
  return 0;
}
```